# pass variable from page load to button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am creating a page that when page load it will connect to the database to check the user status to determine which part can be shown, then user can click submit button which need to connect to the database again to update some information.

So is there a efficient way to do this? now I have to connect to the database twice or is there a method to pass variables from page load event to button click event.

Any idea？ thanks

Comment: Are you worrying about performance issues or code duplication?

Comment: I don't know which one is better? Keep connecting to the database until    session finished or Connecting in every page then close the connection,  in my situation, there may be more than one connecting in a page

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly. All you need to do is extract all functionality which is aware of connecting to a database and then verify permissions in a separate method. Basically, a simple Extract Method technique.

```
public void Page_Load(...)
{
  // check whilst first loading of the page
  // if you need checking each time as page loading - remove if() below
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    YourConnectToDatabaseMethod(defaultParams);
  }
}


public void OnButtonClick(...)
{
   var params = ... grab required params;
   YourConnectToDatabaseMethod(params);
}

private void YourConnectToDatabaseMethod(TypeOfParams params)
{
}
```

Comment: I think he needs a db connection in the case of a non post back too to 'check the user status to determine which part can be shown'

Answer (score 0):

Your database connection most likely comes from a connection pool so even if you call Open, you are not actually reopening a connection but using an already opened one.

Comment: Could you tell me some more detail? I am not sure how to reuse the connection. Right now i just created a connection class

Comment: @pita, which DBMS do you use and which method to connect to that DMBS (ODP.net, ADO.net...)?

Comment: The Data Provider for OLE DB automatically pools connections server side. You don't need to worry about opening connections (but make sure you close them gracefully).